# Rails: hand cursor does not appear

Tags: jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm styling my `rails app` with `bootstrap-sass` and out of nowhere the `cursor hand` does not appear when I hover over a `link_to`.

a few examples of links:

`<%= link_to 'Edit profile', edit_registration_path, :class => 'navbar-link' %>`

`<li><%= link_to "About", about_path, :class => 'navbar-link' %></li>`

Can anyone help me out with this one?

Comment: If you are running Chrome, right click and inspect the link that does not have the correct cursor.  The Chrome dev tools will show you the CSS and will hopefully show you where the `cursor` property is being set or unset.  Can you post the css for `navbar-link`?

Answer (score 0):

Add `cursor: pointer` to the CSS definition of `a.navbar-link`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Tom Aranda!!! Weird... its still not working!!! Restarted the server and all but nothing..